# noudeb default dpkg-buildpackage in pdebuild

Tags: apt, dpkg-buildpackage, pbuilder, pdebuild

I am running pdebuild to build libmaxminddb and noticed it failing after exporting `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES` in the pbuilderrc config file. After some digging I see that `noudeb` is used by dpkg-buildpackage by default it seems, I am unable to find from where, or how.

Now I want to pass `nodoc` in `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES` so it's passed to the `debian/rules` as well as dpkg-buildpackage without `noudeb`, but using `DEBBUILDOPTS` simply pass `nodoc` and `noudeb` remains.
Moreover, the `--profiles` seems also to be silently drop, from what I can see it also just exports `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES`.

(I am unaware of how deprecated pbuilder/pdebuild is, but if there is another toolset for building packages in an isolated pristine environment I am open for suggestion to my bad choice)